# How to get the child code list from the given parent code in database Using MySql or Jpa repository

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a business requirement to write a service that returns the list of child agent codes from the given agent code. this `agent_details` table as below.

[image]

This table agent_code is unique, but reporter_code can be duplicated. every agent has a reporter.
Also, the reporter is an agent. According to this table agent and reporter are linked as follows.

[image]

I need a service to get the list of child agents by giving agent code.
As example when giving `1011` that should returns `[1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010]`

when giving `1005` that should returns `[ 1002, 1003]`.

I am using Jpa repository for this project. my entity class and repository class as follows. How to solve this problem sql query or jpa repository?

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "agent_details")
public class AgentDetails  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "agent_code", nullable = false, length = 16)
    private String agentCode;

    @Column(name = "reporter_code", nullable = false, length = 16)
    private String reporterCode;

    @Column(name = "branch", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String branch;
}

public interface AgentDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<AgentDetails, Long>
{
    AgentDetails findByAgentCode(String agentCode);

    List<AgentDetails> findByReporterCode(String reporterCode);

}
```

Comment: try List<AgentDetails> findByAgentCodeOrReporterCode(String agentCode,String agentCode)

Comment: It is not possible, beacuse of only given agent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (Common Table Expression):
ex.: '1011' as your dynamic parent node.

```
    with recursive
    cte
      (childs) 
    as
      ( select agent_code as childs
        from agent_details where agent_code = '1011'
      union all
        select  g.agent_code as childs
        from cte  a
        join agent_details g
        on a.childs = g.reporter_code
      ) 
    
    select childs as parent_and_childs from cte;
```

and then create a method in your repository that recieve a `List<String>`.

Comment: base-query should be changed as a  `reporter_code= '1011'`

Comment: This was solved my problem. After that I learned more about `Recursion in Sql`. Thank you for your commitment.